# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

This is coding of my `Registration.aspx` file. Whenever I click submit I get

> System.Data.sqlclient.sqlexception:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'

This is the code part.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            // This is the part im getting error in.
            string checkuser = "select count(*) from Table where UserName ='" + uname.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if (temp == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("User Already Exists");
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string insertQuery = "insert into Table (UserName,Email,Password,Country) values (@uname ,@email ,@pass ,@country)";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", uname.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pwd.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("Manager.aspx");
            Response.Write("Registration Successful");
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with jquery nor visual studio. Please take care to tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: Are you sure your table name is `Table`?

Comment: Yes @KartikeyaKhosla

Comment: And neither with MySql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table` is a reserved word , use brackets on this two queries  :

```
"select count(*) from [Table] where UserName ='" + uname.Text + "'";

"insert into [Table] (UserName,Email,Password,Country) values (@uname ,@email ,@pass ,@country)";
```

Comment: Not your fault, but this is not MySql (SqlConnection)

Answer (score 0):

Table is a Keyword so I don't it can be used in this context so make sure your sql query is right

And mysql doesn't use

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query as below,

```
string insertQuery = "insert into [Table] (`UserName`,`Email`,`Password`,`Country`) values (@uname ,@email ,@pass ,@country)";
```